# How to implement this trigger on Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have found an exercise in the SQL book I study, which is not solved and I can not solve it.

The goal is to implement a trigger that avoids overlapping contracts. If a customer with a current contract signs a new one, the end date of the previous one will be one day before the new start date.

Tables given are:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
clientId    VARCHAR2(15),
DNI     VARCHAR2(9),
name        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
surname     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
sec_surname VARCHAR2(100),
eMail       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
phoneN      NUMBER(12),
birthdate   DATE,
CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTS PRIMARY KEY (clientId),
CONSTRAINT UK1_CLIENTS UNIQUE (DNI),
CONSTRAINT UK2_CLIENTS UNIQUE (eMail),
CONSTRAINT UK3_CLIENTS UNIQUE (phoneN),

);

CREATE TABLE contracts(
contractId VARCHAR2(10),  
clientId  VARCHAR2(15),  
startdate DATE NOT NULL,
enddate DATE, 
contract_type VARCHAR2(50),
address     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
town        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
ZIPcode     VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
country     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_contracts PRIMARY KEY (contractId),
CONSTRAINT FK_contracts1 FOREIGN KEY (clientId) REFERENCES CLIENTS
);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How have you tried to solve it, and what problems did you have?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTRACTOVERLAPPED
AFTER INSERT ON CONTRACTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
* this part is giving me problems, i dont know how to express "if client_id from the new contract already exists, check if he has contract and modify the enddate" i know how to change dates but i dont know how to check the condition.                                                                                                                               
END; @Alex Poole

Comment: @KekaBron, please add the code you tried as an edit to your question and tell us exactly which part of it is causing which error. Moreover, do you mean to throw an error when a user enters wrong data or do you want to set a field as per some logic (like setting it to one day prior to the end date of the latest contract)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the posted comments that it helps to have some specifics about what is failing in the prior attempts, and I would also recommend not using a `TRIGGER` at all for this kind of thing.
But as this is for a study exercise, here are some examples that might be a starting place.

I've modified your tables to disallow `NULL` `PRIMARY KEY`s in these examples.

To get started, create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
  CLIENTID    VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
  DNI         VARCHAR2(9),
  NAME        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  SURNAME     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  SEC_SURNAME VARCHAR2(100),
  EMAIL       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  PHONEN      NUMBER(12),
  BIRTHDATE   DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTS PRIMARY KEY (CLIENTID),
  CONSTRAINT UK1_CLIENTS UNIQUE (DNI),
  CONSTRAINT UK2_CLIENTS UNIQUE (EMAIL),
  CONSTRAINT UK3_CLIENTS UNIQUE (PHONEN)
);

CREATE TABLE CONTRACTS (
  CONTRACTID    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CLIENTID      VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
  STARTDATE     DATE          NOT NULL,
  ENDDATE       DATE,
  CONTRACT_TYPE VARCHAR2(50),
  ADDRESS       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  TOWN          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  ZIPCODE       VARCHAR2(8)   NOT NULL,
  COUNTRY       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_CONTRACTS PRIMARY KEY (CONTRACTID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CONTRACTS1 FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTID) REFERENCES CLIENTS
);
```

Then, create the first `CLIENT`s:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTS VALUES (1,NULL,'Frodo','Baggins',NULL,'the.real.frodo@adventure.com',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO CLIENTS VALUES (2,NULL,'Chewbacca','UNKNOWN',NULL,'chewio.@kashyyyk.org',NULL,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Then create a `TRIGGER`.  In this first example, the `TRIGGER` is an `AFTER STATEMENT` type.
It is simple but inefficient since it evaluates *every* `CLIENT` after each `INSERT` statement.
Against a large data set, or in the face of multiple `TRIGGER`s, this could be a problem.
This `TRIGGER` will check for the prior contract and will set its `ENDDATE` to one day before the new contract, if it is null or after the start of the new contract.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTRACT_ENDDATE_ADJUSTER
  AFTER INSERT ON CONTRACTS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO CONTRACTS
    USING (
            SELECT CONTRACTID,
              CANDIDATE_ENDDATE AS ENDDATE
            FROM
              (SELECT CONTRACTS.CONTRACTID,
                 (TRUNC(LEAD(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY STARTDATE ASC) - 1)) AS CANDIDATE_ENDDATE,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC) AS CONTRACT_ORDER
               FROM CONTRACTS)
            WHERE CONTRACT_ORDER = 2) CANDIDATE_CONTRACT
    ON (CONTRACTS.CONTRACTID = CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.CONTRACTID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CONTRACTS.ENDDATE = CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.ENDDATE
    WHERE CONTRACTS.ENDDATE IS NULL OR CONTRACTS.ENDDATE > CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.ENDDATE;
  END;
  /
```

Then, test it out.
Add the initial contracts.  No enddate changes expected, as these are the first.  Frodo's contract here has an end-date already set.

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('Break-Ring',1,TO_DATE('19560511','YYYYMMDD'), TO_DATE('19851014','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, 'No 1', 'Doom Mountain', 'MORD', 'Middle-Earth');
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('SaveGalaxy',2,TO_DATE('19770615','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, NULL, 'No 75', 'Rwookrrorro', 'RWKR', 'Kashyyyk');

SELECT CONTRACTID, CLIENTID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM CONTRACTS ORDER BY CLIENTID ASC, STARTDATE ASC;
CONTRACTID  CLIENTID  STARTDATE  ENDDATE    
Break-Ring  1         11-MAY-56  14-OCT-85  
SaveGalaxy  2         15-JUN-77
```

Then add new contracts.
Frodo's new contract starts before the end of his existing contract, so the enddate will be adjusted.
Chewie's initial contract had no ENDDATE, so it will be adjusted as well.

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('GoBackHome',1,TO_DATE('19570219','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, NULL, 'No 13', 'Hobbiton', 'HBTN', 'Middle-Earth');
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('DefendHoth',2,TO_DATE('19801115','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, NULL, 'Meteor Crater', 'Ice Ridge', 'METEO', 'Hoth');
SELECT CONTRACTID, CLIENTID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM CONTRACTS ORDER BY CLIENTID ASC, STARTDATE ASC;
CONTRACTID  CLIENTID  STARTDATE  ENDDATE    
Break-Ring  1         11-MAY-56  18-FEB-57  
GoBackHome  1         19-FEB-57             
SaveGalaxy  2         15-JUN-77  14-NOV-80  
DefendHoth  2         15-NOV-80
```

And as other contracts are signed, the pattern continues:

```
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('GoWedding',2,TO_DATE('19830309','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, NULL, 'Main Hall', 'Grand Palace', 'ALLNC', 'Coruscant');
INSERT INTO CONTRACTS VALUES('Gardening',1,TO_DATE('19570503','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, NULL, 'No 13', 'Hobbiton', 'HBTN', 'Middle-Earth');
SELECT CONTRACTID, CLIENTID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM CONTRACTS ORDER BY CLIENTID ASC, STARTDATE ASC;
CONTRACTID  CLIENTID  STARTDATE  ENDDATE    
Break-Ring  1         11-MAY-56  18-FEB-57  
GoBackHome  1         19-FEB-57  02-MAY-57  
Gardening   1         03-MAY-57             
SaveGalaxy  2         15-JUN-77  14-NOV-80  
DefendHoth  2         15-NOV-80  08-MAR-83  
GoWedding   2         09-MAR-83
```

To stabilize the workload on this query, a COMPOUND TRIGGER may be used instead.  This second example achieves the same result as the first, but only interrogates the `CONTRACT`s of `CLIENT`s that have changed:

First, `ROLLBACK;`
Then, create a type to be used by the `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
```

Then create the `COMPOUND TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTRACT_ENDDATE_ADJUSTER
FOR INSERT ON CONTRACTS
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  V_CLIENTS NUMBER_LIST;

  BEFORE STATEMENT
    IS
  BEGIN
    V_CLIENTS:= NUMBER_LIST();
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

  AFTER EACH ROW
    IS
  BEGIN
    V_CLIENTS.EXTEND();
    V_CLIENTS(V_CLIENTS.COUNT) := :NEW.CLIENTID;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN

    MERGE INTO CONTRACTS
    USING (
            SELECT CONTRACTID,
              CANDIDATE_ENDDATE AS ENDDATE
            FROM
              (SELECT CONTRACTS.CONTRACTID,
                 (TRUNC(LEAD(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY STARTDATE ASC) - 1)) AS CANDIDATE_ENDDATE,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC) AS CONTRACT_ORDER
               FROM CONTRACTS
               WHERE CONTRACTS.CLIENTID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(V_CLIENTS)))
            WHERE CONTRACT_ORDER = 2) CANDIDATE_CONTRACT
    ON (CONTRACTS.CONTRACTID = CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.CONTRACTID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CONTRACTS.ENDDATE = CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.ENDDATE
      WHERE CONTRACTS.ENDDATE IS NULL OR CONTRACTS.ENDDATE > CANDIDATE_CONTRACT.ENDDATE;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

END CONTRACT_ENDDATE_ADJUSTER;
/
```

After repeating the above inserts, the result is the same:

```
CONTRACTID  CLIENTID  STARTDATE  ENDDATE    
Break-Ring  1         11-MAY-56  18-FEB-57  
GoBackHome  1         19-FEB-57  02-MAY-57  
Gardening   1         03-MAY-57             
SaveGalaxy  2         15-JUN-77  14-NOV-80  
DefendHoth  2         15-NOV-80  08-MAR-83  
GoWedding   2         09-MAR-83
```

Comment: wao i just thought this exercise would have an easy/short answer cause the statement of the exercise is short. But i can see it doesnt. I dont have enough level yet to understand everything you posted since i started to read my book few weeks ago and just read some rules and basic syntax about triggers. Anyways thank you. Im gonna learn a lot, and gonna drive my teacher crazy asking him about all this sentences lol.

Comment: Thanks @KekaBron Yeah with `TRIGGER`s there are often side-effect and performance considerations to take into account.  Often Triggers are avoided entirely if other options like using a procedure can meet the need instead.  Best wishes in your study.  If you have any questions about this post just let me know.  Thanks